# Python error only in open files, not closed files

Tags: python

I'm a beginner python programmer, and I want to know why my code crashes when I open the file, and when I close it, it disappears right away. I'm using visual studio code to write the codes.

This is the type of error that gives:

Unable to import 'tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image'
Unable to import 'numpy'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, if you want to use a module such as numpy, you have to first install it. Do that by opening a cmd.exe and running:

```
pip install numpy
```

Comment: should i do this for all 'import'?

Comment: Yup. If you have things with dots such as tensorflow.keras......., just import the first one, pip install tensorflow. It'll make sure it installs its friends as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `pip install tensorflow` and `pip install numpy` in cmd/terminal. That should install the missing modules.

In Python you need to install the modules that you require, to use them.

Here is a link for further reference : https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html